# Public Email Registration with cPanel/WHM Backend

Tags: php, email, cpanel, whm

I recently started a small hosting and web services operation, using a cPanel/WHM VPS to run the services. I want to offer free email registration to people through a web form. I am wondering how to integrate PHP with cPanel in order to create email accounts for people that complete the form. I do not want them to receive an entire hosting account, just a free email at the domain I choose.

What API's or mods must I install for this. Also, how do I check for multiple registration and integrate some sort of CAPTCHA?

**Edit:** I did do some searching of my own but failed to find any relevant tutorials on the matter. I would greatly appreciate any help with this.

Comment: I am not sure why this question is viewed so negatively, I am just asking for some tips on what direction to go towards with this idea.

Answer (score 0):

that is not good idea for public mail system with cpanel, when ever i am tell you a php script that can create mail account on cpanel.

http://www.zubrag.com/scripts/cpanel-create-email-account.php

for public mail system you can use zimbra mailing system . that have all feature and your can install it on VPS.